# how to allow only floating point number to a text fiedl

Tags: javascript

How to allow only a valid floating point number into a text field
floating point like these only
15
15.41
7045.12
0.74

--only 2 places after the digit
--max one dot
--only positive number so no need for +/-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

and I bet this has been asked here before...

This regex allows integers or floats with one or two decimal places. The integer part is mandatory.

If your intent is not to validate input strings but to find decimal numbers inside a larger string, use this instead:

```
/\b\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b/
```

Comment: @coure06: Then use my first solution. Or did you mean "Either an integer, or a two-digit decimal, but no one-digit decimals"?

Comment: I tried to put ur regex in keypress event but it does not allow me to enter (.)

Comment: You didn't say anything in your question about a keypress event. This is basic information you should have included. If you apply the regex at each keypress then it will not allow the dot because it expects at least one digit after the dot (which you can't have entered yet, of course). So use `/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/`, but be aware that now `1.` will be validated too. If that's OK, then great.

Answer (score 0):

This should work `/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)/` if you want to just match them.
If you want to validate a string - `/^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/`

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/
```